# Packet reassembly at Network Layer libpcap

Tags: c, wireless, tcp, libpcap

**Environment**

As per my understanding `Network layer` is responsible for reassembly of fragmented datagrams and then it supplies the reassembled data to upper `Transport layer`.

I have collected packet traces using `libpcap` and i want to reassemble fragmented packets at layer 3 on my own.

[This link](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPMessageReassemblyProcess-2.htm) says that i need fragment flag, fragment offset, identification number and buffer value for reassembly of segments.

**Question**

At the arrival of first segment how to know what should be size of buffer to  be initialized for complete reassembly of datagram.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP header only gives you the size of the fragment. So you need to reserve a buffer the size of the largest possible IP packet, i.e. 65535 bytes. Only once you get the last fragment can you determine the length of the complete packet.